# Solve a and b if, result = ax + bx*x

Tags: regression, predictive-models, prediction

I have around 100 rows of data. Each row have a result and x. The samples in every row have different values for result and x. How can I analyze these samples and calculate the value of a and b, so that I can easily predict value for "result" when only x is given ?

Comment: It's a polynomial regression without a constant term (or without an intercept.) [Here](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/27024-Poynomial-Regression-through-the-origin) is a discussion with some R codes. Before doing that, some basic knowledge about linear regression will be useful as well. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in microsoft excel. If you have all your Results in column A, all values of $x$ in column B and all values of $x^2$ in column C then you can use a formula like this:

=LINEST(A1:A100,B1:C100,FALSE,FALSE)

The formula above is for the case where you have 100 samples, change "A100" and "C100" accordingly for your own sample size.

For interpreting the results take a look at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LINEST-function-84d7d0d9-6e50-4101-977a-fa7abf772b6d

Comment: This might be correct, but the focus of this website is the underlying statistical principles, as opposed to a focus on programming. Perhaps you could refocus your answer on the statistical results?